# Setting up: running AfterResolveReference taking so long in Android app (Xamarin) Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin

I want to build android application using visual studio 2019 but I'm stuck in this problem. android layout won't show .I want to now what causes this thing and how to solve it.

Thank you in advance for the answers

- I tried to reinstall my VS 2019
- I updated it

[I select activity_main.xml but this was happened, Select to see the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THjtd.png)

Comment: 1. Delete the bin and obj folder to clean and rebuild. 2. Create a new layout of new project to check the Android Design to confirm which cause this isue. 3. Change the version(on the left top of the design)(the version is Android 9.0 or Android 8.0.....). I do not find it on your screenshot. Reopen the layout to check. 4. Upgrade your VS to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you for the comment ,I appreciated it and I followed your comment but I can't select any version, I'm using AMD processor

Comment: Building or rebuilding is also taking so long

Comment: Sorry, i do not have the AMD processor to check. But the four ways could fix some issue normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio 2022, the same message was displayed more than 10 min, with lot of aapt2.exe in my background processes using all my resource, and with no result at the end.

None of the four ways previously explained worked.

I finally displaced the full project folder to my main drive and it worked (don’t know thought if it works because the folder path is shorter or because there is less latency for reading the files)